# Is there a command line tool for windows to burn a directory on the fly, add boot image and verify it?

Tags: windows, command-line, dvd-burning

It doesn't have to be all-in-one thing. But what I want is that doesn't need to create a separate ISO file in temp folders and them burn it but directly from the location.

I only found this http://alexfeinman.com/CreateCD.htm - but it doesn't have verify option.

Maybe there are command line programs that can verify written media against non-iso files on disk, but here is problem with boot image, such tool should have option for that.

Maybe some unix/linux tools that can be run on windows through cygwin ?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot burn and verify without storing the image on any mass storage, at least temporarily.